# how can i make AutoIT send command reliable?

Tags: firefox, upload, webdriver, autoit

Hi guys I'm running a script with AutoIt to insert the path of a file to upload with webdriver.

But the send command is so unreliable it's 50/50 it messes up the characters and the script just stops.

Is there a way to make it reliably input the data? Or maybe how can i confirm that the input is correct, resend, and then send?

This is what i have for the code. It sends the input into the firefox upload window.

```
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send("C:\Users\elsid\Desktop\Eclipse\Workspace\NG - Mentored\Autoit\Test.png")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Java? Then use the Robot class. Or try `WinActivate` after your first line. Might help!

Comment: Yes i am using Java, any link on how to achieve this with the Java robot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way is to use ControlSetText.

Play with AutoitWindowInfo tool and tweak the script below if needed.

```
#RequireAdmin ;Will give your script a permission elevation (sometimes its needed)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 1) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also

WinActivate("File Upload")
WinWaitActive("File Upload","",10)
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
Sleep(2000)
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1","dropdowns.jpg")
```

Comment: I will play around with it, can you explain the "Edit1" what do I put there? or just leave it as is, and where dropdowns.jpg is put the full path of my file correct?

Comment: @Elsid change dropdowns.jpg with your file path. Edit1 should work for you. Here is an info on what edit1 is
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-p3Xmspi3SCU/UWZR8muz2XI/AAAAAAAAAMw/NC1kyvugkpQ/s1600/autoit+control+command.JPG

Comment: More on Autoit WindowInfo https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm

Comment: Autoit has one of the best written help file ever with examples for each function. Use it.

Comment: tried it didn't work. the only one that works is my original script unreliably of course.

Comment: Did you try using Autoit WindowInfo Tool to see if the related control is paired with ControlSetText?

Comment: what do you mean by paired? If the window name is "File Upload"?

Comment: @Elsid Use Window Info Tool to see if the classnameNN for the input you are trying to fill is Edit1 . I edited the code again, try it now.

Comment: yes it is class Edit Instance 1, I will retry your code.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, the script stops because it waits that the window will be focused. To not messes up the characters, use function flag 1 in Send().
Try this way:

```
 While WinWait("File Upload","",1) = 0
  Sleep(500)
 WEnd
 WinActivate("File Upload")
 Send("C:\Users\elsid\Desktop\Eclipse\Workspace\NG - Mentored\Autoit\Test.png", 1)  ;-- flag 1 = keys are sent raw.
 Send("{ENTER}")
```

Good Luck ;)

Comment: it broke again, started typing the characters a few times until it broke.

Comment: While WinWait("File Upload","",1) = 0 ?

Comment: No need to reinvent the weel :)
WinWait("File Upload","") . It will wait indefinately just as your 3 lines code